# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos declaraciones en Java?

Tags: java

En la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2), explican la creación de arrays inicializados poniendo de forma indistinta la posición de `[]` sea antes o después del nombre de la variable/objeto.

Este es el código de ejemplo que ellos usan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si probamos este código todo funciona bien:

```
Exception ae[]  = new Exception[3];
Object aao[][]  = new Exception[2][3];
int[] factorial = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040 };
char ac[]       = { 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ',
                    'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' };
String[] aas    = { "array", "of", "String", };
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ae));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aao));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(factorial));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ac));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aas));
```

**Salida:**

```
[null, null, null]
[[Ljava.lang.Exception;@15db9742, [Ljava.lang.Exception;@6d06d69c]
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040]
[n, o, t,  , a,  , S, t, r, i, n, g]
[array, of, String]
```

Si probamos a cambiar la posición de `[]` en las declaraciones de ejemplo, todo funciona igualmente bien:

```
Exception[] ae1  = new Exception[3];
Object [][]aao1  = new Exception[2][3];
int factorial1[] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040 };
char[] ac1       = { 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'a', ' ',
                     'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' };
String aas1[]    = { "array", "of", "String", };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ae1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aao1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(factorial1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ac1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aas1));
```

**Salida:**

```
[null, null, null]
[[Ljava.lang.Exception;@7852e922, [Ljava.lang.Exception;@4e25154f]
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040]
[n, o, t,  , a,  , S, t, r, i, n, g]
[array, of, String]
```

---

### Pregunta:

**¿Cuál es la diferencia, si la hay, entre declarar un arreglo inicializado de cualquiera de estas dos formas?:**

- **`String aas1[]  = { "array", "of", "String", };`**
- **`String[] aas1  = { "array", "of", "String", };`**

**¿Sabrían a qué se debe que no haya una *uniformidad* en ese sentido?**

Comment: Gracias @Juan. ¿Sabes a qué se debe que no haya *uniformidad*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las dos formas de declarar un array son equivalente, no hay diferencia.

> ¿Sabes a qué se debe que no haya uniformidad?

No lo sabía pero pero leyendo la documentación de Oracle parece ser que la forma "java" de hacer la declaración sería:

```
Tipo [] variable;
```

Pero dejaron la otra forma `Tipo variable []` como un *guiño* a como se declaran en C/C++.

*"Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C and C++. The general rules for variable declaration, however, permit brackets to appear on both the type and in declarators, so that the local variable declaration: ..."*

Que se traduce a:

*"Se permiten los corchetes después de la variable como un guiño a la tradición de C y C++. Sinembargo, la regla general para la declaración de las variables, permite que los corchetes aparezcan en los dos lugares, después del tipo de la variable y después de la variable."*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Se agradece, si es posible, una traducción del último párrafo para quienes no entiendan el inglés. Creo que falta eso para dar la pregunta por respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con que no hay diferencia alguna; de todas maneras se trataría de una cuestión de convención.

```
int[] data;
int data[];
```

Cuando se declara una referencia de array deberían (a mi parecer) ponerse los brackets junto al tipo de dato (`int[] data`, `int[][] data`) en vez de al lado del nombre de variable, de esa manera cualquiera que lea el código puede rápidamente deducir que se trata de un array y no de simplemente un tipo primitivo `int`.

Con los brackets al lado del nombre de la variable, se puede lograr algo como:

```
int num, series[], map[][];
```

Honestamente no sé cuan util sea esta declaración...
por eso, me parece que la primera opción, la de poner brackets inmediatamente junto al tipo (ademas la utilizada por Oracle en toda la documentación) es mas adecuada.

Comment: Realmente no hay diferencia, incluso se puede declarar algo como int [] variable [], y es lo mismo que int [][] variable, o que int variable [][]. No se me ocurriria hacerlo, pero al parecer es válido.